# Chrome New Tab bugging

Tags: google-chrome

So normally when you open a new tab, chrome shows this on the tabs bar

[image]

But when I open a new tab, it shows this

[image]

I know this is kind of is trivial, but it stilll bugs me out..anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=702043

Comment: alright thanks!! This seems to be a server side error...it will porbably be fixed soon! :D